# how to get output of this code. sometimes it shows output and sometime it doesnot?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, arrays

```
    <?php
include 'config.php';
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$sql="SELECT FROM topics where tid='$tid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?> 
<div class="topics"><font size="4"><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></font></div><div class="tdm"><br/><center><img src="http://appricart.com/test/img/<?php echo $rows['photo']; ?>" height="100" width="100"/><br/>
<small><?php echo $rows['message']; ?></small></div>
<?php
}
include 'foot.php';
?>
```

Sometime this code works sometimes it does not please help me with this problem.

It shows this error

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Comment: When there's an error with your query, you still call [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) with `$result`, which is not a legal resource. Also you should notice that the mysql extension is deprecated. You should use a more modern one, like [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO Mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: I assume your query is a copy/paste error, ie. `SELECT title, photo, message FROM ...` or `SELECT * FROM ...` instead of `SELECT FROM ...`. Also, you are open to SQL injection by using a `$_GET` value directly in your query without escaping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$sql="SELECT FROM topics where tid='$tid'"; // here is the error
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

You are not selecting anything from the table topic. hence its showing the error..

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM topics where tid='$tid'"; // this would be better
```

for more info visit [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing any error checks to prevent this. This error is caused when your MySQL query fails to execute. You have a `mysql_query()` statement, and the results are stored into a variable. Later, you're using that variable in `mysql_fetch_array()` statement.

If `mysql_query` fails, it returns `FALSE` which is a boolean value. `mysql_fetch_array` expects it to be a resource instead.

To solve this issue and understand why your query is failing, use the `mysql_error()` function.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) { 
    die('Query failed because: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
//proceed
}
```

---

In this case, you aren't selecting anything from your database, as Sean mentioned above.

Try the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics where tid='$tid'";
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT topics FROM topics where tid='" . $tid . "'";
```

---

[**Also, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).